# Can you identify a location based on the traditional dress in a photo from WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, identification, clothing

Could anyone assist us in identifying the possible location of this photo, based on the woman's dress? My grandfather is in the photo, which was taken during WW2. We know that he served in both the Pacific and European theaters, but this looks more like the American Southwest to me (could she be possibly be Navajo?). We would be grateful for any information / hints.

[image]

Comment: Funny. My knee-jerk reaction looking at her was that she looked Native American (North or South, not sure which). That's tough to really tell from a photo of a single person though.

Comment: Also noticing, forgive me if this is off-base, a strong facial structure resemblence between the woman and the man on the right.

Comment: What did your grandfather do in the war? If, say, an aviator, there were many flight training centers across the southwest...

Comment: @JonCuster, he was in the infantry. We know he was in Hawaii, San Francisco, Guadalcanal and Germany, but that's it. Regretfully his records were destroyed in the National Personnel Center fire in 1973, so the information we have is incomplete.

Comment: @T.E.D. Funny you mention that – we also commented that their faces look quite similar (the man on the right is my grandfather!).

Comment: I don't suppose there's any possiblity that the woman is your great (or great-great) grandmother? The hands (and lack of teeth?) seem to indicate an older person, but the cheeks when they smile are amazingly similar, nose similar shape, smiles similar, and the angle they are holding their bodies at is the same. Its fairly common for parents to attend when kids graduate basic training today. I don't know if it was back then (IIRC, unnessecary travel was being discoraged during the war).

Comment: @T.E.D. I would be a bit surprised, as my grandfather was a country boy from north Georgia, but I suppose anything is possible.

Comment: Very reminiscent of New Mexico pueblos. The Santa Fe ran through there.

Comment: That is anything but not a "traditional dress"... But the background is rather distinctive for some areas of the US. Steep sandstone cliffs of a light color, similar to the uniform color.

Comment: @T.E.D. It is also somewhat customary that after completing basic training, soldiers get a weekend off and get leave to attend special occasions. However I don't know how that was during WW2

Comment: New Mexico and Arizona were more flight schools than basic training. But a little time off while going cross-country by train might have been doable, particularly if they had leave while shifting from the Pacific to European theaters.